# How can I print debug string in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-debug

Are there simple ways to print debug strings in Rails? Something like the [`OutputDebugString()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) in Windows.

Comment: Are you just looking for output to standard out? If so, you can always use "puts". Otherwise, I'm not sure what the OutputDebugString() command does - can you tell us more about what you're looking for?

Comment: It works with the small program called DbWin.exe. Basically, a special console dedicated to the debugging purpose. Debug string appears in DbWin's console window.

Comment: 'puts' works great with the functional test code. I didn't think the answer was so simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

"To write in the current log use the logger.(debug|info|warn|error|fatal) method from within a controller, model or mailer:"

```
logger.debug "Person attributes hash: #{@person.attributes.inspect}"
logger.info "Processing the request..."
logger.fatal "Terminating application, raised unrecoverable error!!!"
```

You could also use raise object.inspect.

Or, if you want more powerful debugging tool, take a look at pry: http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails

`binding.pry` in your code and you'll be able to debug ALL THE THINGS!